# Cannot import libc::funcs

Tags: rust

I'm trying to change the UID of the running user. The [documentation says that you should use `libc::funcs::posix88::unistd::setuid`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.4.0/libc/funcs/posix88/unistd/fn.setuid.html).

When I try to compile, it prints an error:

```
Could not find `funcs` in `libc`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, it says that it's unstable, meaning you should avoid using it if at all possible.  Unstable things can disappear or change at any time without warning.  In particular, that's for the compiler-internal `libc` which you're not supposed to touch.

Secondly, that's from Rust 1.4, where the current version is 1.18.  With the error you're getting, I assume you're using a different version of Rust to 1.4.

If you want to use `libc`, you should use [the `libc` from the Cargo ecosystem](https://crates.io/crates/libc).  You can then find [`setuid` in its API reference](https://doc.rust-lang.org/libc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/libc/fn.setuid.html).